# How can i fix my website navigation font from changing across pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I'm doing some work on a website but can't figure this out at all! For some reason the font in the nav bar on the homepage is smaller then on the rest of the site. the site is built using wordpress and I have never had this issue before!

I have been trying to use the chrome dev tools to figure it out but so far i haven't been able to find a solution. if somebody has the time to take a look and can help me figure this out I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Howmepage: http://www.abbeyvideoproductions.com/

On the homepage you can see the font in the nav is smaller and sits further to the left of the nav bar as a result compared to any other page on the site:

Other page example: http://www.abbeyvideoproductions.com/packages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with % font-size.

Try to define the font-size and line-height with px

style.css (line 903)

```
.builder-module-navigation {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 37px;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, the problem source was ``.hentry`` had ``font-size: 112.5%;`` except on your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete property form `.builder-module-navigation li a`  `font-size: 112.5%;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML isn't valid. Don't start with a `div`!

You have two places with different stylesheets

- post-teasers-left/style.css vs. post-teasers-right/style.css
- style-home.css vs. style-pages.css

So, this would be the first place to investigate.

In your case, you have a different `font-size`, although it is defined as `112.5%` in both cases. From [`MDN - font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/CSS/font-size)

> Percentages refer to the parent element's font size

This means, you must look at some ancestor's `font-size`. When you go up the heirarchy, you will find that in one case it is `font-size: 100%`, and in the other case it's `font-size: 1em`.

To solve your problem, you can either redefine the font-size with absolute values in the nav bar as @kkern already suggested, or use the same values in both parent's font-size.